# How share common project between dockerized .net core applications?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I want to share a common project containing data contracts between 2 dockerized .net core applications. My solution has the following structure.

```
Solution.sln
/packages
/src
  /webapi (Dockerized)
  /server (Dockerized)
  /messages (shared)
```

I could put the Dockerfile next to the sln file, but then I will be able to have only one file. How can organize the solution in a better way? Placing shared project in a seperate solution and publishing into own nuget server is an overkill imho.

Comment: I have been struggling to find a solution to this common scenario as well. Please post the answer if you run across it thanks.

Comment: @wchoward check my reply

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solutions to this problem:

1. Create a nuget package to have assembly sharing
2. Move Docker files to the upper/or root folder in your solution and add suffix to them eg. Dockerfile.myService and Dockerfile.myService2
3. use docker-compose and set the context to the rootfolder, but in this case you will be able to build your images only from docker-compose

I hope it helps.